# Can I pass an anonymous type as a parameter to a function?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities, anonymous-types

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199093/why-cant-i-pass-an-anonymous-type-as-a-parameter-to-a-function) i realized that i cannot pass an anonymous type as a parameter to a function. So what other options do i have?

Perhaps, passing a `Query.ToList` as parameter would help, or am i re-inventing the wheel?

**Update:** I have the following query, which i would like to pass to a function:

```
Sub Test
    Dim Query = (From c In DB Select New With { .ElementName = c.Name })
    DoSomething(Query)
End sub

Private Function DoSomething(ByVal Q as object) as string
    Dim Query = From c In Q Select c
End Function
```

And the error i get is

> Expression of type 'Object' is not queryable

Comment: What do you mean? `ToList` will return a `List` of a specific type suck as `List<String>`, therefore you must declare it in your method.

Comment: Have you tried passing an anonymous type to a parameter of type dynamic..

Comment: @rabs No i haven't tried that yet

Comment: How are you going to use the objects in the collection? Inside DoSomething you can't access the properties of the anonymous type. If you show an example of what you are trying to accomplish we might be able to help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After reading this post i realized that i cannot pass an anonymous type as a parameter to a function. So what other options do i have?

The post is telling lies. Of course you *can* pass anonymous types to a method.

```
Function DoSomething(Of T)(items As IEnumerable(Of T))
    …
End Function

Dim Query = (From c In DB Select New With {.ElementName = c.Name})
DoSomething(Query)
```

In either case, your definition of `DoSomething` was the problem since of course `Object` isn’t a queryable object. `ToList` doesn’t help at all, since the result is *still* a collection of anonymous types.

Comment: Hmm wondering what anonymous data is and how they got into the system in the first place if they are unknown :p Yeah Yeah I know what you mean just like the term "anonymous data" :)

Answer (score -1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx

Thought I'd try out some other dynamic options, and it appears that you *can* pass a pure anonymous type via dynamic (i.e. in addition to the dictionary or expando options above).

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        dynamic d;
        int i = 20;
        d = (dynamic) i;
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test2()
    {
        dynamic d;
        int i = 20;
        d = (dynamic)new { a = 1, b = 12.2, c = "some text" };
        MethodA(d);
        Console.WriteLine(d);
    }

    public void MethodA(dynamic o)
    {
    }
```

Additional options: ExpandoObject.

Comment: -Rune FS-: Agreed.  However, it *appeared* to me that @Chocol8
was specifically asking for an anonymous way of doing it.  Generics are always better from a performance standpoint, but sometimes dynamic / anonymous types fit the bill very nicely.

Comment: This is just so wrong. Performance apart, dynamic doesn't run on extension methods (which Linq is). Imaginary -1 :)

Comment: You are correct on those two technical points, but your generalisation "this is so wrong" is not.  Dynamic does have its place.  Do you know when to use it?  SO is a democracy.  I don't mind your -1 ;)

Comment: dynamic has a place everywhere except with extension methods. It doesnt work simply. That's all..